# Refresh div every two seconds using ajax without jquery

Tags: php, ajax

I made a chat website. And it has a `div` with `id=chatlogs`. I want it to get chatlogs from logs.php every 2 seconds. How can I do that? I want to use ajax with it and avoid using jquery.

Comment: `setInterval( ajax,2000 );` - where ajax is your complete function for sending and processing the request

Comment: Im stuck and waiting for u guys to help me make a auto refresher. Can u explain more in depth RamRaider? thanks in advnace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do smoething like this:

```
<script>
    setInterval(refresh_logs(), 2000); // 2000 = 2 Seconds

   function refresh_logs()
   {
      var xmlhttp;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
      else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
          {
           document.getElementById("logs_div").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
          }
        }
      xmlhttp.open("POST","get_logs.php",true);
      xmlhttp.send();
   }
   </script>
```

Comment: @Bido262 Please check now. Just added pure Javascript ajax. This will work for you.

Comment: can u take off the activeX object. Im using an updated version of browser. i dont need the activeXobject pls remove them. Coz ill get screwed if i remove them myself thanks in advance and pls remove them.

Comment: I understand  that you are using updated version but some users does not use latest. So they might face issue with old versions. If this code is working for you then keep it like that.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out.